# Sublime 3 Package for Jade Syntax Highlighter,Linting,Auto Complete etc

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, mean-stack

I have installed the Sublime Text suggested packages, however nothing seems to work well for syntax highlighting, code linting and auto suggestion. Can someone suggest a complete package for Jade.

Comment: Have you tried the package called [Jade](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Jade) on Package Control? It's syntax highlighting works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

The `Jade` package on Package Control has 146,000 installs at the time of commenting. I'm pretty sure it works fine.

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Jade

> A highlighter using Python instead of JavaScript is also included for use with PyJade, you can either manually select Jade (Python) from the syntaxes list or give your file the extension .py.jade to select automatically (only on Sublime Text). Also included is a test.py.jade file that can be compiled with pyjade to test it.

You'll need to install Package Control first before installing any packages from there. It's really easy to do, just follow the instructions here. https://packagecontrol.io/installation (make sure you choose the correct version).

Comment: Some time this package is not highlighting properly the jade syntax issues :(

Comment: Do we have any jade file watcher for Sublime 3 text like Webstorm has?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into similar issues and would try a few things first:

1. First, if you happened to have your Jade file open when you did the install, you just need to close the file and re-open it to see package working.
2. If Step 1 isn't the issue, see if the package is enabled. `Package Control > Enable Package > Jade`. If you don't see it in the list of available options, that means it's already enabled. If it is in the list, then enable it.
3. If it is already enabled, first disable it with `Package Control > Disable Package > Jade` then re-enable it with `Package Control > Enable Package > Jade`.
4. Restart Sublime (probably not needed, but doesn't hurt).

This should get the package working for you.